# Is this Possible with Unpivot?

Tags: sql, view, pivot, unpivot

I have a table like this:

**ForeignKeyA,  ForeignKeyB,  Before1,  After1,  Before2,  After2, ... Before(n), After(n)**

I need to be able to create a view that unpivots this table into something like this:

**ForeignKeyA,  ForeignKeyB,  Year, Before,  After**

where Year is the iteration of the Before/After columns.

**Edit: I've gotten to this point now, but I'm not sure how to separate the year out into it's own column.**

```
    SELECT [f_lForiegnKey], [f_lAnalysisVariableKey], dBefore, dAfter, szBefore,     szAfter
    FROM 
    (SELECT [f_lForiegnKey], [f_lAnalysisVariableKey], [dBefore01], [dAfter01],   [szBefore01], [szAfter01],
    [dBefore02], [dAfter02],[szBefore02], [szAfter02],
    [dBefore03], [dAfter03],[szBefore03], [szAfter03],
    [dBefore04], [dAfter04],[szBefore04], [szAfter04],
    [dBefore05], [dAfter05],[szBefore05], [szAfter05]

    FROM [dbo].[A_STRATS_V]) p
    UNPIVOT
    (dBefore FOR dBeforex IN ([dBefore01], [dBefore02], [dBefore03], [dBefore04],     [dBefore05])) AS U1

    UNPIVOT
    (dAfter FOR dAfterx IN ([dAfter01], [dAfter02], [dAfter03], [dAfter04], [dAfter05])) AS U2

    UNPIVOT
    (szBefore FOR szBeforex IN ([szBefore01], [szBefore02], [szBefore03], [szBefore04], [szBefore05])) AS U3

    UNPIVOT
    (szAfter FOR szAfterx IN ([szAfter01], [szAfter02], [szAfter03], [szAfter04], [szAfter05])) AS U4

    WHERE RIGHT(dBeforex, 1) = RIGHT(dAfterx, 1) 

    AND RIGHT(dBeforex, 1) = RIGHT(szBeforex, 1) 

    AND RIGHT(dBeforex, 1) = RIGHT(szAfterx, 1);
    GO
```

I need to truncate the number off each set and put it in its own column. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do I have the sneaking suspicion that `A_STRATS_V` is actually a view?  What RDBMS?  Can we get sample starting data and desired results here?  Especially as I'm not sure how you're planning to get `year`...

Comment: The V stands for variables. It's a table in SQL Management Studio, although it needs to be able to translate to Oracle as well. 

I'm not sure of how to get the year yet. I was actually able to get it working by grabbing the number off of the end of the column names and putting it in a year field for each iteration, but I've been told that that wouldn't be possible/practical later on.

Comment: Still waiting for sample starting data and desired results.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible. I can't dig up my code, but here's something similar

[unpivot with dynamic columns plus column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775409/unpivot-with-dynamic-columns-plus-column-names)

Basically, you go fetch the column names from sysobjects and write dynamic sql to unpivot.