# How is an nvarchar being populated in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775409/unpivot-with-dynamic-columns-plus-column-names), the person starts out with the following block of code:

```
-- Build list of cols we want to unpivot (skip PID & UID)
declare @cols nvarchar(max) 
select @cols = coalesce(@cols+N',', N'') + quotename(c.name) from syscolumns c
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'
where o.name = 'MyTable' and c.name not in ('PID', 'UID') order by c.colid
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how @cols is populated in that way.  When I take out the variable definition, `@cols =`, it returns a list.  When I take out the `coalesce()` and put only `@cols+N','`, `select @cols` is just null.

Can anyone point me in a direction where I can find out how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think of it as assigning a value to a variable in a loop. The variable is assigned for each row in the `select` statement. Since the variable retains its value between each row, this allows you to create a concatenated list of values comming from the rows of a table.

The reason `select @cols = @cols + N','` doesn't work, is that the `@cols` variable is initially NULL. When you concatenate any string to a string that is NULL, the result will also be NULL. That's why you use `coalesce`. Alternatively, you could have initialised the `@cols` variable to an empty string.