# Unpivot columns from another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have used Unpivot to get data from a table I am trying to manipulate. I use this query to rearrange my columns to rows;

```
SELECT        Id, ownername, ownervalue
FROM            Contacts UNPIVOT (ownervalue FOR ownername IN (column1, column2, column3)) unpiv;
```

This works great. However I would prefer to get my column names from another table instead of hard-coding them in the query.  Ideally i would like this, but it does not work;

```
SELECT        Id, ownername, ownervalue
FROM            Contacts UNPIVOT (ownervalue FOR ownername IN (SELECT * FROM ColumnsTable)) unpiv;
```

Is it possible to get my list of columns from another table like this?

Comment: columnlist present in `IN` clause should be present in `Contacts` table while `Unpivoting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong) it is not possible to use dynamic columnnames without the use of a dynamic query, which is executed with for example `exec`.

Take a look at the following question [unpivot with dynamic columns plus column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775409/unpivot-with-dynamic-columns-plus-column-names)