# Dynamic Unpivot and split Columns SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, unpivot

I have a table as MarketOutput that has 20 Columns

```
[Region] [LOB]  [GWP 2013]  [GWP 2014]  [LR 2013]   [LR 2014]
-------------------------------------------------------------
North  Workers  38902.50     37,972,404   89             82
```

I would like to dynamically change column to rows. Region and LOB are fixed columns, [GWP 2013], [GWP 2014], [LR 2013], [LR 2014] are dynamic columns.

For next year they will be `[GWP 2015]`, `[LR 2015]`

I want to unpivot the column and split the [GWP 2014] as two column [GWP], [2014].

The output should be like

```
Region  [LOB]      [Metrics] [Year] [Value]
--------------------------------------------------
North   Workers    GWP       2013         38902.50 
North   Workers    GWP       2014    37,972,404
North   Workers    LR        2013            89
North   Workers    LR        2014            82
```

Can you please suggest how it can be done?

I am new to pivoting in SQL Server

I would also like to insert the output into a new table every time with dynamic list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unpivot with dynamic columns plus column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775409/unpivot-with-dynamic-columns-plus-column-names)

Comment: You should really consider also fixing your database. At least the year should be a value in the row, maybe also LR / GWP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to split the columns after do the [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) something like this:

```
WITH Unpivoted 
AS
(
    SELECT region, lob, columns, value
    FROM Regions
    UNPIVOT
    (
       columns
       FOR value IN([GWP 2013] , [GWP 2014] ,
                    [LR 2013]  , [LR 2014] ,
                    [GWP 2015], [LR 2015])
    ) AS u
) 
SELECT 
  region, 
  lob,
  columns,
  CAST(CASE WHEN value LIKE 'GWP%' THEN REPLACE(value,'GWP ', '')
       WHEN value LIKE 'LR%' THEN REPLACE(value,'LR ', '')
  END AS INT) AS Year,
  CASE WHEN value LIKE 'GWP%' THEN 'GWP'
       WHEN value LIKE 'LR%' THEN 'LR'
  END AS Metrics
FROM Unpivoted;
```

And then of course you should do it dynamically to avoid listing the columns manually and do it dynamically:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(column_name)
                      FROM information_schema.columns
                      WHERE table_name = 'Regions'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Region' 
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'LOB'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');


SELECT @query = 'WITH Unpivoted 
                AS
                (
                    SELECT region, lob, columns, value
                    FROM Regions
                    UNPIVOT
                    (
                       columns
                       FOR value IN('+ @cols + ')
                    ) AS u
                ) 
                SELECT 
                  region, 
                  lob,
                  columns,
                  CAST(CASE WHEN value LIKE ''GWP%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''GWP '', '''')
                       WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''LR '', '''')
                  END AS INT) AS Year,
                  CASE WHEN value LIKE ''GWP%'' THEN ''GWP''
                       WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN ''LR''
                  END AS Metrics
                FROM Unpivoted';


EXECUTE(@query);
```

This should work fine assuming that:

- All the columns `[GWP 2013] , [GWP 2014] , [LR 2013]  , [LR 2014] , [GWP 2015], [LR 2015], ... etc` are in the same format (GWP or LR then space then the year, and
- All of the columns are of the same data type `int` or decimal, if the data types are not the same you should cast all of them into one data type before doing the `unpivot` otherwise you will got an error.
- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68c8e/2)

This will give you:

```
| region |     lob |  columns | Year | Metrics |
|--------|---------|----------|------|---------|
|  North | Workers |  38902.5 | 2013 |     GWP |
|  North | Workers | 37972404 | 2014 |     GWP |
|  North | Workers |       70 | 2015 |     GWP |
|  North | Workers |       89 | 2013 |      LR |
|  North | Workers |       82 | 2014 |      LR |
|  North | Workers |       80 | 2015 |      LR |
```

---

### **Update:**

I used [`FOR XML PATH('') ..`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to concatenate all the list of values in one string, it is a work around in SQL Server to do that. The value of `@cols` will be the string: `[GWP 2013], [GWP 2014], ...`.

If your fields data type are different, you have to do the cast of all the columns that will be unpivoted in the anchor query before doing the `UNPVOT` like this:

```
SELECT @query = 'WITH Unpivoted 
                AS
                (
                    SELECT region, lob, columns, value
                    FROM 
                    (
                       SELECT 
                         region,
                         lob,
                         CAST([GWP 2013] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [GWP 2013],
                         CAST([GWP 2014] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [GWP 2014],
                         ... etc
                       FROM Regions
                    ) AS t
                    UNPIVOT
                    (
                       columns
                       FOR value IN('+ @cols + ')
                    ) AS u
                ) 
                SELECT 
                  region, 
                  lob,
                  columns,
                  CAST(CASE WHEN value LIKE ''GWP%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''GWP '', '''')
                       WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''LR '', '''')
                  END AS INT) AS Year,
                  CASE WHEN value LIKE ''GWP%'' THEN ''GWP''
                       WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN ''LR''
                  END AS Metrics
                FROM Unpivoted';
```

If you found it hard to write the cast for all the columns manually, you can generate it dynamically and append it instead, for example:

```
DECLARE @colsCasted AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @colsCasted = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        'CAST(' + QUOTENAME(column_name) + 'AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS ' + QUOTENAME(column_name)
                      FROM information_schema.columns
                      WHERE table_name = 'Regions'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Region' 
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'LOB'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
```

Then in the dynamic query append that value to it:

```
SELECT @query = 'WITH Unpivoted 
                    AS
                    (
                        SELECT region, lob, columns, value
                        FROM 
                        (
                          SELECT region, lob,
                          ' + @colsCasted + '
                          FROM Regions
                        ) AS t
                        UNPIVOT
                        (
                           columns
                           FOR value IN('+ @cols + ')
                        ) AS u
                    ) 
                    SELECT 
                      region, 
                      lob,
                      columns,
                      CAST(CASE WHEN value LIKE ''GWP%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''GWP '', '''')
                           WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''LR '', '''')
                      END AS INT) AS Year,
                      CASE WHEN value LIKE ''GWP%'' THEN ''GWP''
                           WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN ''LR''
                      END AS Metrics
                    FROM Unpivoted';


    EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: This  works like charm. Can you please explain how xml_path works?

Comment: You also mentioned that i need to cast, as all my fields are not either int or decimal, some are nvarchar. This casting needs to be done in a separate dynamic Query? or would be part of @Query?

Comment: what does this mean FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

Comment: @Mohit - I update my answer to clarify all these doubts, please see my update in the answer.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud for clarifying. Really appreciate the effort

Comment: @Mohit - You're welcome any time, glad I could help :)

Comment: I am getting error when running the query   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '('  .

Comment: In the last Query you have written colsCasted  and cols both do we need both?

Comment: @Yes, you need both, one for the cols names, and the other for the column with cast. In the orginal query add this new `@colsCasted = ..` and decalre it and then replace it with the modified @query statement in the last update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92941/discussion-between-mahmoud-gamal-and-mohit).