# SQL Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unpivot

From my database table(Customer) I need to select one record and display the result by interchanging columns to rows.

EG:
actual result

```
| ID | Name | Age |
| 1  | Tom  | 25  |
```

expected output

```
| Name | Value|
| ID   | 1    |
| Name | Tom  |
| Age  | 25   |
```

**Other details:**

1. Customer table has different number of colums in different databases
2. I need to do this inside a function (So I cannot use dynamic queries, UNPIVOT)

Please advice me.

Comment: You have to somehow hard-code all of the column names, otherwise using a dynamic query becomes obligatory.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos- since columns are vary how can I hardcode all. eg: one database table may have ID, Name, Age, Address and another may have ID, Name, Age.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot

Comment: What RDBMS & version?  SQLs implementation of Pivoting varies by engine and by version.

Comment: @xQbert-SQL server 2008

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY-**exec sp_executesql** is not possible within a function

Comment: Looks to me bluefeet has already provided an answer to this based on @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY's comment.  Why does it have to be a function?  Why not a procedure?

Comment: @NewDeveloper you can use stored procedure. It will be supported

Comment: @xQbert; @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY- no. We need to do a code change if we are using a stored proceedure.

Comment: @NewDeveloper You have to use dynamic sql I'm afraid.

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236741/dynamic-unpivot-and-split-columns-sql-server-2012

Comment: SQL CLR is an option

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql, so exec has to be in the solution. Are you able to have a function that produces the query string and run the exec outside of the function?

Answer (score 1):

This uses CROSS APPLY with VALUES to perform unpivot

```
--Set up test data
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST(ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),Name VARCHAR(20),Age TINYINT)

INSERT INTO  dbo.TEST VALUES
('Shaggy',32)
,('Fred',28)
,('Velma',26)
,('Scooby',7)



DECLARE @table VARCHAR(255) = 'Test'
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(255) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @ID INT = 2

--Create a VALUES script for the desired table
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT
    @col = COALESCE(@col,'') + '(''' + c.name + ''' ,CAST(A.[' + c.name + '] AS VARCHAR(20))),' 
FROM
    sys.objects o
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c
            ON
            o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    o.name = @table
    AND
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = @schema
ORDER BY
    c.column_id

--Remove trailing ,
SET @col = LEFT(@col,LEN(@col)-1)

--Build Script for unpivoting data.
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(2000) = '
SELECT
    CAST(C.Col AS VARCHAR(20)) AS [Name]
    ,CAST(C.Val AS VARCHAR(20)) AS [Value]
FROM
    [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] A
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES ' + @col + ') C(Col,Val)
WHERE
    A.ID = ''' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(8)) + ''''

--Run Script
EXEC (@str)
```

Comment: Since I need to done this inside a function, I am not able to use 'EXEC' within it.